# How to partly color the border with css

Tags: html, css, colors, border

I want to partly color the border of a circle. This means I need to configure the color of the foreground as well as of the background.

[image]

Comment: CSS Pie Timer - http://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0o52513j/10/)

[image]

You could do it like this. I've used the 33% and 67% slices anti-clockwise.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="div div-p">
    <div class="div-c"></div>
    <div class="div div-1">
        <div class="div div-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div div-3">
        <div class="div div-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.div-p {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px;
}
.div-c {
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
}
.div-1 {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px 100px 100px 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.div-2 {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px 50px 100px 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    background-color: #009999;
}
.div-3 {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px 100px 100px 50px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.div-4 {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px 50px 100px 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(61.2deg);
    transform: rotate(61.2deg);
    background-color: #009999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [linear-gradient - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

## [DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/k5aczj3m/)

MARKUP:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

STYLE:

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    height:150px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #EC5F51;
    border: 2px solid #EC5F51;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position:relative;
}
div:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 114px;
    height: 114px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 18px;
    top: 18px;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(126deg, transparent 50%, #ccc 50%),
        linear-gradient(90deg, #ccc 50%, transparent 50%);
}

div:nth-child(2) {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 50%, #ccc 50%),
        linear-gradient(90deg, #ccc 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

[image]